# D3 + React - The whole force graph is redrawn when updated data arrives instead of updating only links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm quite new in D3.
I would like to draw a graph using the data received from JSON (the graph contains nodes connected with each other by links with a given percentage of occupancy). After the first query from the database, the graph looks correct. After a few seconds, I send another query (to update the data on the use of links) and unfortunately, instead of updating only the text (linkOccup), the whole graph is deleted and redrawn (with correct updated data).
I would like only the information about occupancy of links to be updated instead of redrawing the entire graph. Does anyone know the solution to the problem?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import useResizeObserver from './useResizeObserver';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { select } from 'd3';

function ForceGraph({ linksData, nodesData }) {
  const svgRef = useRef();
  const wrapperRef = useRef();
  const dimensions = useResizeObserver(wrapperRef);

  const links = linksData;
  const nodes = nodesData;

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);
    if (!dimensions) return;

    svg.attr('viewBox', [
      -dimensions.width / 2,
      -dimensions.height / 2,
      dimensions.width,
      dimensions.height,
    ]);

    const drag = simulation => {
      const dragstarted = d => {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
      };

      const dragged = d => {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
      };

      const dragended = d => {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
      };

      return d3
        .drag()
        .on('start', dragstarted)
        .on('drag', dragged)
        .on('end', dragended);
    };

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force(
        'link',
        d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.dpid)
      )
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1200));

    const link = svg
      .selectAll('line')
      .data(links)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append('line').attr('class', 'new-element'),
        update => update.attr('class', 'updated-element')
      )
      .attr('stroke-width', 2)
      .attr('stroke', '#000')

      .call(drag(simulation));

    const node = svg
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(nodes)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append('circle').attr('class', 'new-element'),
        update => update.attr('class', 'updated-element')
      )
      .attr('r', 18)
      .call(drag(simulation));

    const linkOccup = svg
      .selectAll('text')
      .data(links)
      .join(
        enter =>
          enter
            .append('text')
            .text(d => {
              if (typeof d.max_link_occupancy !== 'undefined') {
                return d.max_link_occupancy + '%';
              } else {
                return d.bw + ' Mb/s';
              }
            })
            .attr('class', 'new-element'),
        update =>
          update
            .text(d => {
              if (typeof d.max_link_occupancy !== 'undefined') {
                return d.max_link_occupancy + '%';
              } else {
                return d.bw + ' Mb/s';
              }
            })
            .attr('class', 'updated-element')
      )
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
      .attr('font-size', 18)
      .call(drag(simulation));

    const label = svg
      .selectAll('.label')
      .data(nodes)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append('text').attr('class', 'new-element'),
        update => update.attr('class', 'updated-element')
      )
      .text(d => {
        return d.dpid;
      })
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
      .attr('font-size', 18)
      .attr('fill', 'white');

    simulation.on('tick', () => {
      link
        .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);

      node.attr('cx', d => d.x).attr('cy', d => d.y);

      label
        .attr('x', d => {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr('y', d => {
          return d.y;
        });

      linkOccup
        .attr('x', d => (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2)
        .attr('y', d => (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2);
    });
  }, [linksData, dimensions]);

  return (
    <div className="rootNew" ref={wrapperRef} style={{ marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
      <svg className="svgNew" ref={svgRef}></svg>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ForceGraph;
```

Comment: Hi, I can see only the enter part of the update pattern. If you want to update the chart, you will also need to implement the update part inside the join

Comment: If you are creating new objects to represent the nodes each update, then the force will have to reinitialize them (giving them new positions) as the positional data is stored on this object.

Comment: @AndrewReid and CarlosMoura, I corrected my code using your comments: I do not create new objects every time the data is updated and I added the update function to join. Unfortunately, the problem still exists. Could you please check my code again?

Comment: Where are the variables `linksData` `nodesData` coming from each update? You're updating these in place and not creating new references? I think you are still creating new objects when you query for the new data.

Comment: Looking at the console. I do not create new elements but update the current ones: https://gifyu.com/image/V9iW

Comment: The data comes from my application backend on the localhost. They are taken as follows and set in new state: function getBorderLinks() {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/service/border-links")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setGclLinks(res));
  }

Comment: Then ForceGraph is invoked as follows: <ForceGraph
              linksData={gclLinks.links}
              nodesData={gclLinks.nodes}
            />